# How do I pass my password to gksu?

Tags: password, gksu

`gksu` doesn't has an option like `sudo` has to pass the password to it in the following way:

```
echo 'password' | sudo -S command
```

Anyway I wonder which is the simplest way to pass my password to `gksu`. What I found until now is:

```
parallel -j 2 -- "gksu command" "( sleep 1; xdotool type 'password';  xdotool key 'Return' )"
```

But this doesn't look so good for me (`parallel` and `xdotool` must to be installed, there is some time spent until the password is passed, the window which asking password is not avoided).

So, is there a better way?

---

Note: I'm not interested to edit the `sudoers` file or in explanations like "*don't do this, it's not safety!*".

Comment: Why are you uninterested in using `sudoers`? That is the most sensible solution here of which I am aware.

Comment: Why are you using `gksu` if you want to pass the password from a script ?

Comment: @HalosGhost I like to keep `sudoers` file as it is. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. "_Why_?"

Comment: @Leiaz Why not? I'm aware about `pkexec`, but then the question will be the same for `pkexec`.

Comment: @HalosGhost Yes, it is: my sudoers file remain untouched.

Comment: I meant, why don't you just use sudo or su ?

Comment: @Leiaz [Because](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `gksu` and `gksudo` pass your password to `sudo`.  Try running them in a terminal with the `--debug` option:

```
gksu --debug gedit
```

You'll notice that they run `sudo` with the `-H` option (as well as `-u` and `-p` for username/password and `-S` option to avoid a terminal).

Therefore, you really just need to use `sudo -H` instead of `gksu` or `gksudo`.

Comment: This is a good proof. I can agree with it for now, thanks.